# NWIS data retrieval will not function with variable

Tags: python, variables

I am attempting to load USGS data with the NWIS file retriever repository [Link](https://github.com/USGS-python/dataretrieval). However, the dataretrieval function does not work properly when variables are utilized for the start and end date.

Attempts to convert the variables to strings with str(date.today()) and strftime result in the same issue.

Code is below:

```
!pip install dataretrieval
import dataretrieval.nwis as nwis

lastday = date.today()
firstday = (date.today()-datetime.timedelta(days=7))
site = '11502500'
pcode='0060'
lastday=lastday.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
firstday=firstday.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
#print(firstday)
#print(lastday)

df=nwis.get_record(sites=site, service='dv', start=firstday, end=lastday, parameterCd='pCode')
df.head()
```

If I manually enter the dates within the function i get the correct data. When i use variables (converted to strings), incomplete data is received

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation string of the function:

```
        start: string
            Starting date of record (YYYY-MM-DD)
        end: string
            Ending date of record.
```

You're passing `date` objects, not strings, for these parameters. You need to format them.

```
lastday = date.today().format('%Y-%m-%d')
firstday = (date.today()-datetime.timedelta(days=7)).format('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, however i'm now thinking that their is an issue with the code itself. I converted the dates into strings with strftime, but the data returned is still the incorrect dates. I've edited the code above to show the most current results

Comment: If the only difference is whether you hard-code the dates or use variables, I don't see how that could be. Once the date reaches the function it's the same.

Comment: Don't change the question to match the answer. Now my answer makes no sense in context.

Comment: So the issue is with the dataretrieval function?

Comment: You mean `nwis.get_record()`? I don't see how that could be, it gets the same parameters each time.

Comment: Yes, If i pass variables for start and end in nwis.get_record(), i get an incomplete set of data.
If the start and end dates are manually entered, a complete data set is returned.

Comment: You must be giving different dates. Otherwise there's no difference as far as the function is concerned.

Comment: that is why i have the variables printed out to double check.

Comment: I'm totally out of ideas. The same dates should produce the same results. There's no difference between literals and the result of `.format()`.